# Compare fastlane/gym with xcode build

Tags: fastlane, fastlane-gym

I have an ionic 3 application that behaves differently when built via fastlane-gym vs. Xcode.

When built with fastlane-gym, the ionic app exhibits some readily reproducible UI refresh issues, that promptly disappear when the app is built with XCode.  It does not appear to be a race condition.  There are no runtime errors of any kind visible in either builds of the app.

What is a way to even begin troubleshooting this?  My initial thought was look at the build parameters that XCode uses and compare them.  However, I am not sure how to accomplish this.  What other ways are there to identify differences between the two builds?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: How exactly are you building the app using `gym`? (Best add your build lane to your question). What exactly are the "readily reproducible UI refresh issues"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An app is just a zipped folder. So rename it to `.zip`, unzip it, then compare the contents of the folders. They should be pretty much identical. If not, find out if this could lead to the behavior you are describing.

Also: https://github.com/ionic-zone/fastlane-plugin-ionic exists as a way to build an Ionic app via Fastlane using the `ionic` (and `cordova`) CLIs. Maybe this gives you a better result than building with `gym` directly.

Comment: Thank you so much for both insights!  I am comparing the zip file contents now.  I also was not aware of the fastlane ionic plugin.  I'll be sure to report back.